# MySQL Workbench - Error Authentication with old (insecure) passwords

Tags: mysql-workbench

When I try to use MySQL Workbench utilities (`mysqldbexport`, `mysqldbimport`, etc.) I always receive this error message:

```
>mysqldbexport --server=user:password@ip_address:3006 database 
# Source on ip_address: ... ERROR: Cannot connect to the Source server. 
Error Authentication with old (insecure) passwords is not supported: http://dev. 
mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html
```

The remote server is running with the `--old_passwords` option and the password in the mysql. User table was created using the old hash algorithm (short password).

Had anyone had such situation? How can I fix it?

- Remote MySQL version: 5.0.77
- MySQL Workbench version: 5.2.38 CE Revision 8753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the MySQL Workbench Utilities will not support logging with the old password format. I think the proper way to go here is to upgrade the users password to the new format thus taking advantage of the increased security.

I haven't done this, but here's a helpful comment from the link you posted:

> if you are using the OLD password() function and want to setup the
>   mysql scheme to the new password system.
>
> it isn't possible to login to your mysql.exe console with
>
> mysql -u root -p your_password (!) you have to blank your login
>   password to gain access to your mysql console.
>
> on windows you have to type the following (please are sure that the
>   mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql is in your bin\ directory!  You will
>   find this script in your scripts\ folder of your mysql installation.
>
> mysql -u root --force mysql < mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql
>
> best regards  thE_iNviNciblE

Try that and restart the server without the `--old_passwords` option. You should consider too upgrading your MySQL Server to a newer version since the MySQL team is dropping support for the MySQL 5.0 branches (they are not going to be a part of active maintenance routines: no new fixes, etc.).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Sergio.  That's exactly the solution.  Additionally from the MySQL forum, I received the following answer:
    
_The underlying Connector/Python does not support the old  authentication protocol and never will. [...]  
If you remove the --old-passwords, authentication should still work   fine. Then create a user which will use the newer, secure password   hashing. That user can then be used for tools like mysqldbexport  (making sure it has proper permissions of course)._